# Tensorflow placeholder problems: error: you must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float error

Tags: python, input, tensorflow

I am implementing a convolutional autoencoder that has to reduce the dimension of camera images per image at real time. Therefore my batch size is one. Y_pred is the output of the network. I want to evaluate this so I can see what my network is outputting.

This is the code I use to import my data and feed the placeholders:

```
def inputs(image_file_path):
    filenames = [image_file_path]
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
    read_input = read_image(filename_queue)
    return read_input

with tf.Session() as sess:

    image = inputs(file_path)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord = coord)


    image = tf.cast(image/255, tf.float32)
    ###data is just one image, so I set the dimension [batch, height, width, channels] to [1,120,160,3]
    image = tf.reshape(image, [1, 120,160,3])
    X_data = image.eval()



    sess.run(train_step,{X_input:X_data, Y_true: X_data})

    output = Y_pred
    ###Everything works fine up until this point.
    print(Y_pred.eval())

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Then the placeholders are here:

```
     X_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,120,160,3])  
     Y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,120,160,3])
```

The error I'm getting:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1039, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1021, in _run_fn
status, run_metadata)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
     next(self.gen)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
      [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Julian\workspaceNeon\Scriptie\Autoencoder\__init__.py", line 164, in <module>
     print(output.eval())
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 569, in eval
     return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3741, in _eval_using_default_session
     return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 778, in run
     run_metadata_ptr)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 982, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
 [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

 Caused by op 'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "C:\Users\Julian\workspaceNeon\Scriptie\Autoencoder\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
X_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,120,160,3])
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1507, in placeholder
name=name)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 1997, in _placeholder
name=name)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

 InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for      placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
      [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: You need to pass data while using `Y_pred.eval()`

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'pass data'? I got the same error when using this:

        `print(sess.run(output.eval(),{X_input:X_data, Y_true: X_data}))`

Comment: `print(sess.run(output,{X_input:X_data, Y_true: X_data}))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it worked.

Comment: You didn't understand what were you calling. when you are calling `sess.run`, you are actually calling an operation, or in other words, you are telling tensorflow to do some computation. And then the real computation and the whole things needed for this computation are managed by tensorflow itself. You just need to believe that the engineers in google are smart enough to do what you are imaging.